# access the entry page in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a project in laravel that I did a long time ago and I don't remember how to enter the page. It is in the folder: http: // localhost / laravel / Foro_armonicas / This is the routes file: (the entry route is "login"):

```
<?php
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::get('/login', function () {
        return view('login');
    });
    Route::post('validar_login', 'ControllerLogin@validar')->name('validar_login');
    Route::get('/registro', function () {
        return view('registro');
    });
    Route::post('guardar_registro', 'ControllerLogin@guardar_registro')->name('guardar_registro');
    Route::get('volver', 'ControllerLogin@volver')->name('volver');//este es el de la pagina inicial
    Route::get('desconectar', 'ControllerLogin@desconectar')->name('desconectar');
    Route::post('/nuevo_post', function () {
        return view('nuevo_post');
    });
    Route::post('controladorNuevoPost', 'ControllerLogin@NuevoPost')->name('controladorNuevoPost');
    Route::get('ver_post/{post_id}', 'ControllerLogin@ver_post')->name('ver_post');
    Route::post('controladorNuevaRespuesta', 'ControllerLogin@NuevaRespuesta')->name('controladorNuevaRespuesta');
    Route::post('controladorGuardarRespuesta', 'ControllerLogin@GuardarRespuesta')->name('controladorGuardarRespuesta');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install laravel. Then browse to your project folder using Visual code or any other editor of your choice  and open the folder.I am assuming you want  to run your project on your local machine.
Click on Terminal button on top of your visual code(if you are using visual code).
Type the following code on your terminal:

```
php artisan serve
```

Then go to your browser and type

```
localhost:8000
```

and you will see your home page.

Comment: If I remerber, use this if you only need to execute php, no SQL database

Comment: if mysql or any other database is involved then you need to go to the env file on your code editor to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do a `vhost`, the entry point id the `public` folder :

http://localhost/laravel/Foro_armonicas/public

VHost sample :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.ext
    DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/my-laravel/public/
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/my-laravel/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: indeed it was that: http://localhost/laravel/foro_armonicas/public/index.php/login (i finally remember it) but what can I do to make it this?: http://localhost/laravel/foro_armonicas/public/index.php/

Comment: I don't get your point, why would you set url like this ? And how would be urls for login or registro ? http://localhost/laravel/foro_armonicas/public/index.php/registro ? Not a good idea